# Updation of some columns of table in MySql procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have one procedure, which i access from asp.net application.
I have update and insert query in it for some columns of a table and i want remaining column values as it is. what should i do?Please Help..

Answer (score 1):

You should check the link below which has full details.

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/387/connecting-to-sap-data-from-aspnet/ this connects with VS 2003 & VS 2005

To connect using VS 2008 check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35876/Connection-to-SAP-from-Visual-Studio-2008-with-SAP